# Duplicate Nodes in a Mobx state tree

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-state-tree

What's the best way to handle duplicate nodes in a tree which are part of separate subtrees.
For suppose I've multiple Docs in root store. Each doc has fields and there are fields common between the docs. But at a time only 1 doc is active so I've a reference type named CurrentDoc of type doc.
As and when a doc becomes a current doc all it's fields are fetched.

Comment: Can you post some code or example of what you have tried so far?

Comment: @Wolfie
t goes something like this.
https://ibb.co/f2qPS76
I can't put the field in the root store as they belong to the Document and are direct descendants.
Is not there a way to isolate a subtree or something. Or have composite identifier like composite Primary key

Comment: What is the problem you are having or trying to solve?

Comment: I want to have two nodes with same ids in two different subtrees.

Comment: https://spectrum.chat/mobx-state-tree/general/duplicate-nodes-in-subtree~bbbbd9e0-6259-40bd-b4a6-3e8d5de80ed